# Django-Rest-Framework 3.0 ImproperlyConfigured at /api/users/ Field name `is_owner` is not valid for model `User`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Have some strange bug in my project. I was remove is_owner field from user's model, made migrations and now when i'm sending post request to my user's endpoint i have this exception.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `is_owner` is not valid for model `User`.

But i can't found any place in project, using Ctrl Shift F, where old i_owner field still can be called. In ruquest i using this field nowhere too.

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFbQZ.png)

Comment: Please share your model you are using, serializer and so on. Are you inherating `User` or are you using your own model? Please provide more information. Please do not link images. If the link is broke, we cannot see anythink. Insert the image directly.